# Using ng-bootstrap 11.0.0-beta.x with Angular 13 rc

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I wonder if it's possible to use ng-bootstrap 11.0.0-beta.x with Angular 13.0 rc? Any thoughts whether these two are compatible?

How should I install  ng-bootstrap 11.0.0-beta.x ? Is it something like:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@11.0.0-beta.x
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest release matching the mask ng-bootstrap@11.0.0-beta.x is [11.0.0-beta.2](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/releases/tag/11.0.0-beta.2). Release notes:

> This release adds Angular 12 support for the Bootstrap 5 beta version along with a couple of bugfixes.

As you can see, Angular 13 compatibility was not tested. There is still a chance it would work though.

Comment: okay, I'll  give it a try with Angular 13

Comment: Did it work for you? I get an error when trying to import the module.

Comment: @ArcadeRenegade yes, it worked for me. I'm having a problem, not with bootstrap itself, but the fact that it defines basic css styles for html elements.